# AbstractValidator for Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

```
internal sealed class MeetingValidator : AbstractValidator<Meeting> 
{
    public MeetingValidator()
    {
      RuleFor(m => new { m.Start, m.End })
        .Must(d => d.End - d.Start > 0)

      // Other Rules
    }
}
```

Is there a way to declare a AbstractValidator on an anonymous type ?

This is for refactoring purposes.

The test is common to other types than Meeting and I want to minimize the duplication of my code.

```
internal sealed class EndDateValidator : AbstractValidator<????> 
{
    public EndDateValidator ()
    {
      RuleFor(m => ????)
        .Must(d => d.End - d.Start > 0)
    }
}


public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, ????> MustHaveAEndStartDate<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T,  ????> ruleBuilder)
{
    return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new EndDateValidator());
}


internal sealed class MeetingValidator : AbstractValidator<Meeting> 
{
    public MeetingValidator()
    {
      RuleFor(m => new { m.Start, m.End }) // or something else
        .MustHaveValidEndDate()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this, anonymous types are really just types you haven't given a name to and are generally meant to stay internal to the method, so you are better off creating a class and using that.

Comment: Of course, if you have an anonymous type, then chances are it is internal to a single method so makes no sense to use an external validation method.

Comment: Anonymous types are types that cannot be named in source code, they can only be inferred. For instance the method `Foo(new { x = 1 })` works because the `T` in `Foo<T>(T t)` can be inferred by the compiler at the call site. I.e. you don't have to explicitly specify it. If you can refactor your problem to only work with inferred generic types then you can solve it. But it seems unlikely.

Comment: To avoid code duplication you can use different approaches:  
- use an interface with `Start` and `End` properties and derive your classes from it;
- use a  `Period`  type (probably is a good choice to use a [`Record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record)) with `Start` and `End` properties to be used as `Period` property in your classes or to use instead of the anonymous type in your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can't refactor the source class(es) (here: `Meeting`), then you can use a `(DateTime Start, DateTime End)` `ValueTuple` instead of an anonymous type, defining the validator as inheriting from  `AbstractValidator<(DateTime Start, DateTime End)>`.

```
internal sealed class MeetingValidator : AbstractValidator<Meeting>
{
    public MeetingValidator()
    {
        RuleFor<(DateTime, DateTime)>(o => new(o.Start, o.End))
            .MustHaveValidEndDate();
    }
}

internal sealed class EndDateValidator : AbstractValidator<(DateTime Start, DateTime End)>
{
    public EndDateValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o).Must(o => o.End > o.Start);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, (DateTime Start, DateTime End)> MustHaveValidEndDate<T>(
        this IRuleBuilder<T, (DateTime Start, DateTime End)> ruleBuilder
        )
    {
        return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new EndDateValidator());
    }
}
```